Spring Kafka: consume from source cluster and produce to target cluster: produced records are still sent to source cluster
I have an application that uses Spring Boot (3.3.5) + Spring Kafka.
The application interacts with two Kafka clusters:

A source cluster to consume from
A target cluster to produce to

The following is the main configuration for this:
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiClusterConfiguration {

    @Value("${kafka.source.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String sourceBootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.target.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String targetBootstrapServers;

    // Consumer Factory for source cluster
    @Bean("sourceConsumerFactory")
    public ConsumerFactory<Void, byte[]> sourceConsumerFactory(@Value("${spring.application.name}") String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, sourceBootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, VoidDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    // Consumer Container Factory for source cluster
    @Bean("sourceKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Void, byte[]> sourceKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            @Qualifier("sourceConsumerFactory") ConsumerFactory<Void, byte[]> sourceConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Void, byte[]> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(sourceConsumerFactory);
        // Batch incoming records reduce round-trips
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        factory.setBatchInterceptor((records, consumer) -> {
                log.debug("Consuming batch from source (size: {})", records.count());
                return records;
        });
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new InitialAssignmentRebalanceListener());
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler());
        return factory;
    }


    // Producer Factory for target cluster
    @Bean("targetProducerFactory")
    public ProducerFactory<UUID, byte[]> targetProducerFactory(@Value("${kafka.target.producer.config.transactional-id-prefix}") String txId,
                                                             @Value("${kafka.target.producer.config.linger-ms}") int lingerMs,
                                                             @Value("${kafka.target.producer.config.batch-size}") int batchSize,
                                                             @Value("${kafka.target.producer.config.max-request-size}") int maxRequestSize,
                                                             @Value("${kafka.target.producer.config.max-retries}") int maxRetries) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, targetBootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, UUIDSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);

        // Configurable producer properties
        props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, txId);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, lingerMs);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSize);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, maxRequestSize);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, maxRetries);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    // Kafka Template for target cluster
    @Bean("targetKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<UUID, byte[]> targetKafkaTemplate(@Qualifier("targetProducerFactory") ProducerFactory<UUID, byte[]> targetProducerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(targetProducerFactory);
    }

    // Transaction manager for target producer
    @Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<UUID, byte[]> kafkaTransactionManager(@Qualifier("targetProducerFactory") ProducerFactory<UUID, byte[]> targetProducerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(targetProducerFactory);
    }

And here is my listener class (some details omitted):

@Slf4j
@Service
public class KafkaForwardingService {

    private final KafkaTemplate<UUID, byte[]> targetKafkaTemplate;
    private final String targetTopic;
    private final List<String> sourceObservabilityHeaders;

    public KafkaForwardingService(@Qualifier("targetKafkaTemplate") KafkaTemplate<UUID, byte[]> targetKafkaTemplate,
                                  @Value("${kafka.target.topic}") String targetTopic,
                                  @Value("${kafka.source.observability.header-names}") List<String> sourceObservabilityHeaders) {
        this.targetKafkaTemplate = targetKafkaTemplate;
        this.targetTopic = targetTopic;
        this.sourceObservabilityHeaders = sourceObservabilityHeaders;
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "${kafka.source.topic}",
            containerFactory = "sourceKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    @Transactional
    public void listen(ConsumerRecords<Void, byte[]> sourceRecords) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        for (var sourceRecord : sourceRecords) {
            Headers sourceHeaders = sourceRecord.headers();

            var recordKey = parseEntityId(sourceHeaders);
            var eventType = parseEventType(sourceHeaders, recordKey);

            // Process the record only if it is an invoice or a cancelation
            if (isCorrectEventType(eventType)) {

                int partition = getSourcePartition(sourceHeaders, recordKey);

                Headers targetHeader = setupTargetHeaders(sourceHeaders, recordKey, eventType);


                ProducerRecord<UUID, byte[]> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(
                        targetTopic,
                        partition,
                        recordKey,
                        // Pass through value of record as-is without any deserialization
                        sourceRecord.value(),
                        targetHeader
                );

                // Send to cluster 2
                try {
                    CompletableFuture<SendResult<UUID, byte[]>> send = targetKafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
                    send.get();
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    log.error("Encountered exception while sending to target cluster", ex);
                    throw ex;
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    log.error("Interrupted while sending to target cluster", ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

And here is my application.yaml config:
server.port: 28080
spring:
  application:
    name: kafka-bridge

kafka:
  source:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:39092 # <--------------------
    topic: source-topic
    observability:
      # These headers will be copied into the target record.
      header-names: A,B,C
  target:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:39093 # <--------------------
    topic: target-topic
    producer.config:
      max-retries: 3
      transactional-id-prefix: ${spring.application.name}-${random.uuid}
      max-request-size: 196608
      linger-ms: 100 # Default 0ms
      batch-size: 131072 # 128kB. Default 16384 = 16kB


management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
  endpoint:
    env.show-values: WHEN_AUTHORIZED
    configprops.show-values: WHEN_AUTHORIZED
    additionalKeysToSanitize: user.info

server:
  error:
    include-message: always

The basic processing scenario is:

A batch of records is consumed from source
Some processing of the message keys/headers takes place
The processed records are produced to target, transactionally

To verify this, I created two Kafka clusters using Docker: kafka1 and kafka2. I produce some messages to kafka1 and see whether they are processed.
Then, a transaction is initiated:
2024-10-30T16:23:34.220+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] Instantiated a transactional producer.
2024-10-30T16:23:34.233+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.7.1
2024-10-30T16:23:34.233+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: e2494e6ffb89f828
2024-10-30T16:23:34.233+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1730301814233
2024-10-30T16:23:34.234+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] Invoking InitProducerId for the first time in order to acquire a producer ID
2024-10-30T16:23:34.239+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [idge-producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] Cluster ID: 7W22NXM7Q2CzGi2mJJXa6Q
2024-10-30T16:23:34.241+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [idge-producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] Discovered transaction coordinator kafka2:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)
2024-10-30T16:23:34.344+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [idge-producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] ProducerId set to 1005 with epoch 0
2024-10-30T16:23:34.356+01:00  INFO 255073 --- [kafka-bridge] [idge-producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=kafka-bridge-producer-1, transactionalId=kafka-bridge-5fc9c170-4bf8-4dd7-a325-83283522baa60] Cluster ID: RByNz2bTRNCOYtsAR7ojfg


which has coordinator kafka2 as desired.
However, the message is still produced to kafka1!
I have verified that the Spring Boot KafkaAutoConfiguration is not being called.

After some more debugging, it seems that the metadata fetch update in (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer#waitOnMetadata) forces the producer cluster metadata to be incorrectly updated:
Before metadata.fetch():

After metadata.fetch():

But I'm still not sure why this is occurring seeing how I have no ProducerFactory set up for my source cluster. Where is this erroneous config coming from?

Sounds like a problem in the Apache Kafka client by itself. Would be great to have some simple project from you to reproduce. Thanks

See if client.dns.lookup can help you some how: https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.18/kafka-configuring/topics/kafka-client-dns-lookup-property.html. Looks like your kafka2 is resolved to kafka1.

Looks like your kafka2 is resolved to kafka1 D'oh. That was a rather dumb mistake. You are correct, due to some misconfiguration in my docker-compose.yml, kafka2 was getting resolved to kafka1. Once I ran the application in a container on the same network and tried to connect via the internal hostnames, everything worked.
If you'd like to post the same info as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Glad to see that  you have resolved the problem, but I'm not very good with Docker and network. So, please, go ahead and add answer to your question yourself. I just don't know what to say to describe the problem and solution for it.
